# How implement OnKeyDown event in TFrame

Tags: delphi, events, frames, keyevent

To solve some problems in our system, I need to implement the events  `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyPress` in Frames (TFrame). Currently did a palliative solution, but it is very ugly and present any problems.

The process is more or less the following:

1) I created the event `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyPress` in a base class inherited from TFrame.

2) In a standard form based on TForm, implemented a control that intercepts execution keys. So, this process execute first key events on frame and after key events on the form.

I had to do way, because I wanted the OnKeyDown events execute before in frame and after on the Form. The implementation work, but I'll think in better code.

Can anyone suggest a better solution? Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure, but I think the original question needs this edit:

1. I created two event handlers: OnKeyDown and OnKeyPress in my TFrame.

2. In the TForm that uses the TFrame, I wrote two event handlers which I hooked up to the TForm's OnKeyDown and OnKeyPress.  These event handlers first call the TFrame's methods of the same name.  Depending on the result of those calls, the TForm event handlers may then process the key themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more tests and got a simpler solution that principle worked without problems.

1) I get an object of type base of my frame through a recursive function.

2) If the active control is inclue in standard frame, call the OnKeyDown, OnKeyPress event execution.

If someone needs something, below is the code of my application testing.

```
Unit UnFrameBase;

Interface

Uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, ActnList;

Type
  TFrameBase = Class(TFrame)
    PnlBase: TPanel;
  Private
  Public
    Procedure EventFrameKeyDown(Sender: TObject; Var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); Virtual;
  End;

Implementation


{$R *.dfm}

{ TFrameBase }

Procedure TFrameBase.EventFrameKeyDown(Sender: TObject; Var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
Begin
  //nothing
End;

End.


Unit UnControlsClassTest;

interface

uses Classes, Controls;

Function ActiveControlAs(AControl: TWinControl;
  AClass: TWinControlClass): TWinControl;

    Function CheckControl(Var C: TWinControl; ControlClass: TWinControlClass): Boolean;
    Var
      Parent: TWinControl;
    Begin
      Result := (C Is ControlClass);
      If (Result = False) And (C <> Nil) And (C.Parent <> Nil) Then
      Begin
        Parent := C.Parent;
        Result := CheckControl(Parent, ControlClass);
        If Result Then
          C := Parent;
      End;
    End;


Var
  C: TWinControl;

Begin
  C := AControl;
  If CheckControl(C, AClass) Then
    Result := C
  Else
    Result := Nil;

End;


Unit UnMainFormTest;

Interface

Uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ComCtrls, UnFrameCustomer,  UnFrameBase;

Type
  TFormMain = Class(TForm)
    Procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    Procedure BtnTestarClick(Sender: TObject);
    Procedure FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; Var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
  Private
    Function GetInstanceActiveFrame(AActiveControl: TWinControl): TFrameBase;
  Public
    { Public declarations }
  End;

Implementation

Uses UnControlsClassTest;

{$R *.dfm}


Function TFormMain.GetInstanceActiveFrame(AActiveControl: TWinControl): TFrameBase;
Begin
  Result := TFrameBase(ActiveControlAs(AActiveControl, TFrameBase));
End;

Procedure TFormMain.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; Var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
Var
  LActiveFrame: TFrameBase;

Begin
  LActiveFrame := GetInstanceActiveFrame(ActiveControl);
  If Assigned(LActiveFrame) Then
    LActiveFrame.EventoFrameKeyDown(Sender, Key, Shift);

  If Key In [VK_DOWN, VK_RETURN] Then
  Begin
    Perform(WM_NEXTDLGCTL, 0, 0);
    Key := 0;
  End
  Else If Key = VK_UP Then
  Begin
    Perform(WM_NEXTDLGCTL, 1, 0);
    Key := 0;
  End;
End;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Instead of creating a TFrame descendent, create KeyDown and KeyPress procedures in the frame like

```
procedure TFrame2.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('KeyDown: '+IntToStr(Key));
end;

procedure TFrame2.KeyPress(var Key: Char);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('KeyPress: '+IntToStr(ord(Key)));
end;
```

Then call them from the OnKeyDown and OnKeyPress of the form like

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  Frame21.KeyDown(Key,Shift);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  Frame21.KeyPress(Key);
end;
```

Comment: Hi @crefird. Currently is exactly this what I do. But my way is generic when my class TMyForm intercept any frame type TMyFrame.

My idea was to create a solution maybe a little different, however, if there is no other way, I'll have to leave it at that.